# Failed to test special characters using contains() in webdriver

Tags: java, automation, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, assertion

I want to verify whether the particular text is present on the page or not.

I used the following code:

```
driver.getPageSource().contains("String to check");
```

The above code is working only for the string which is not having any Special characters. If the string has any special characters(`"",|,!,&` etc) as mentioned it fails.

Is there any way to check the particular text on the page or not?

I'm using "Selenium standalone server - 2.20.0"

The following is my WebDriver Java code:

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String a[])
    textCheck(driver, "welcome, Mani | LogOut");
    static void textCheck(WebDriver driver, String strToCheck){
    boolean blCond = driver.getPageSource().contains(strToCheck);
    if(blCond ){
        System.Out.Println("True");
    }else{
        System.Out.Println("False");
    }
}
```

Now I want to check whether the string `"welcome, Mani | LogOut"` is present or not in the loaded page.

Comment: What do you mean by fails? Returns `false` when it should be `true`? Exceptions? Compiler errors?

Comment: how do check for strings with special characters?

Comment: It returns false. if the text is having any special characters. I'm passing the string as a parameter.

Comment: @Manigandan please show us how you are really doing it. Or is your actual code `driver.getPageSource().contains("String to check");` ??

Comment: @jlordo: Please see the question. i posted how i'm proceeding.

Comment: can you also post the (relevant) source code of the web page? I don't think the page source contains `"welcome, Mani | LogOut"`.

Comment: @jlordo: I used `http://shop.airtel.com/`. Login by any user and u can find the text in right corner of the page.

Comment: @Manigandan I won't do your work. You can do that in a browser, look at the page source and copy the relevant part. Add it to your question. I think the mystery will be solved quickly after you have done that.

Comment: @jlordo: This is the piece of code i'll get after i select the text and click the view selection source. `<div class="login-message">welcome, <a href="/my-account" class="user-name">suganya</a> | <a href="/logout" class="logout">Logout</a> </div>`

Comment: You have two checks in your code (`textCheck(...)` and `...contains(...)`).  Which one isn't doing what you expect?  If the former, what does `textCheck()` do?  It isn't part of Selenium's API.

Comment: @Ross: textCheck() is used to call a method contains. My real code is in contains method i.e. `driver.getPageSource().contains(strToCheck);`.

Comment: I strongly suspect your page source does not contain what you think it does.  You should print out the result from `driver.getPageSource()` and examine it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I'll compose an answer based upon your question and comments. You use

```
boolean blCond = driver.getPageSource().contains(strToCheck);
```

when trying to decide if `strToCheck` is on your page or not. In your case `strToCheck` is `"welcome, Mani | LogOut"`. You use the `contains()` method on the source of the page. In a comment later, you say (the relevant part of) the page source is

```
"<div class=\"login-message\">welcome, <a href=\"/my-account\" class=\"user-name\">suganya</a> | <a href=\"/logout\" class=\"logout\">Logout</a> </div>"
```

Look at that string. It does not contain the character sequence `"welcome, Mani | LogOut"`.

The longest substring to match what you are looking for would be

```
"welcome, <a href=\"/my-account\" class=\"user-name\">suganya</a> | <a href=\"logout"
```

Hope this helped you to understand why your code is not working as you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected boolean isTextPresent(String text){
    try{
        boolean b = driver.getPageSource().contains(text);
        return b;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
  }
```

Do assertion by calling the above method as below:

```
assertTrue(isTextPresent("welcome, Mani | LogOut"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is the best, I think:

```
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
try {
      assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("BODY")).getText().matches("^[\\s\\S]*welcome, Mani | LogOut[\\s\\S]*$"));
    } catch (Error e) {
      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }
  }
```